# "Can't find any code sections in symbol file" when debugging x86 assembly via GDB

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb

I have a university task to watch the stack content affected by my program.

I was given the following code  `dodawanie.s`:

```
.code32
SYSCALL = 0x80
SYSEXIT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0
SYSWRITE = 4
STDOUT = 1

.global _start

.data
liczba1:
    .long 0x10304008, 0x701100FF, 0x45100020, 0x08570030
liczba2:
    .long 0xF040500C, 0x00220026, 0x321000CB, 0x04520031

number1:
    .long 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x01, 0xFF
number2:
    .long 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xE1, 0xEE

_start:
mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
mov $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
int $SYSCALL
```

And a makefile code provided by the instructor:

```
all: dodawanie

dodawanie: dodawanie.o
    ld dodawanie.o -o dodawanie

dodawanie.o: dodawanie.s
    as --gstabs dodawanie.s -o dodawanie.o
```

After I type `gdb dodawanie` the following communicate occurs `Can't find any code sections in symbol file`. The instruction to this class says every line should be read into gdc after executing it. Can somebody help me understand what is going on?

I added `-g` into the makefile like this:

```
all: dodawanie

dodawanie: dodawanie.o
    ld -g dodawanie.o -o dodawanie

dodawanie.o: dodawanie.s
    as -g --gstabs dodawanie.s -o dodawanie.o
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: Shouldn't the code be in the `.text` segment?

Comment: You don't need to define your own `SYSEXIT` and `SYSWRITE`; use `#include <sys/syscall.h>` to get the definition of `SYS_EXIT`.  (Build with `gcc -m32 -g -c dodawanie.S`, note the capital S to use the C preprocessor.  Or `gcc -m32 -g -nostdlib -static dodawanie.S` to assemble+link in one command).  Also don't use `.code32`; that only lets you put 32-bit machine code in a 64-bit object file / executable, which you don't want.  `as --32` or `gcc -m32` already implies `.code32`.